# synchronized statement for a particular code snippet

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code snippet from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

```
public void addName(String name) {
  synchronized(this) {
    lastName = name;
    nameCount++;
  }
  nameList.add(name);
}
```

1. I think `nameList.add(name);` also needs to be in synchronized block since nameList content should also be happen-before relationship like  Collections.synchronizedList(List).

Any thought on this?

2. And it also says

> Without synchronized statements, there would have to be a separate,
>   unsynchronized method for the sole purpose of invoking nameList.add.

I don't understand this sentence why nameList.add should be in a separate unsynchronized method if there is no synchronized statements.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit weird. Without more details (on the docs' part), it's hard to know. I think what they're getting at is that you should always be careful invoking third-party code while holding a lock, but this isn't a great example. But you could imagine a `List` implementation that, for instance, writes to an RDBMS and waits for the response -- a potentially long operation, during which you're holding the lock. In worst case, if the List acquires a lock and then calls a callback that synchronizes on your object, you could even deadlock.

Answer (score 4):

By this example, they are trying to show how to partially synchronise a method, and particularly, code involving `lastName` and `nameCount`. Read this:

> In this example, the addName method needs to synchronize changes to
>   lastName and nameCount

So, maybe `nameList` is already synchronized or changes to it do not need to be in sync with changes to `lastName` and `nameCount` variables. Hence, it's left out of synchronized block.

Comment: The important part is not what you quoted, but the part that comes after: "but also needs to avoid synchronizing invocations of other objects' methods. (Invoking other objects' methods from synchronized code can create problems that are described in the section on Liveness)." The other object's method may do a blocking call to another thread that calls addName again -> Deadlock.

Comment: Hi @NickL, can you say in detail why it make deadlock happen?

Answer (score 1):

I understand the example as trying to show that you should avoid calling other object's methods from synchronized blocks as *Starvation* may happen, because other object's method may take long time to finish.

It does not seem critical(maybe not a requirement?) for the list to guarantee the order, as opposed to `lastName` and `nameCount` which should.

Comment: Not just Starvation, also Deadlock and Livelock. The other object's method may do a blocking call to another thread that calls `addName` again -> Deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand this sentence why nameList.add should be in a separate unsynchronized method if there is no `synchronized` statements.

They are merely saying that if the language did not provide the `synchronized` statement, then the only way to synchronize anything would be to write `synchronized` *methods*.  They're saying that would be awkward because sometimes you want to mix synchronized and unsynchronized code in the same method.  If there was no such thing as a `synchronized` statement, then you'd have to write something like this instead:

```
public void addName(String name) {
  addName_subroutine(name);
  nameList.add(name);
}

private synchronized void addName_subroutine(String name) {
    lastName = name;
    nameCount++;
}
```

The snippet is supposed to be an example of wanting to mix synchronized and unsynchronized code, but they don't go very deep into the reasons why you might want to write it that way.

Comment: They do give the reason why `nameList.add(name)` is not synchronized: "but also needs to avoid synchronizing invocations of other objects' methods. (Invoking other objects' methods from synchronized code can create problems that are described in the section on Liveness)."

Comment: @NickL,  It's a fair cop.  Changed my text.